# Optimize GROUP BY after ranged index query

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, group-by

I have a content application that needs to count responses in a time slice, then order them by number of responses. It currently works great with a small data set, but needs to scale to millions rows. My current query won't work.

```
mysql> describe Responses;
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| site_id       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| content_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| response_id   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| date          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The table type is InnoDB, the primary key is on (content_id, response_id). There is an additional index on (content_id, date) used to find responses to a piece of content, and another additional index on (site_id, date) used in the query I am have trouble with:

```
mysql> explain SELECT content_id id, COUNT(response_id) num_responses
               FROM Responses
               WHERE site_id = 1
                 AND date > 1234567890
                 AND date < 1293579867
               GROUP BY content_id
               ORDER BY num_responses DESC
               LIMIT 0, 10;
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Responses | range | date          | date | 8       | NULL |  102 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

That's the best I've been able to come up with, but it will end up being in the 1,000,000's of rows needing to be counted, resulting in 10,000's of rows to sort, to pull in a handful of results.

I can't think of a way to precalculate the count either, as the date range is arbitrary. I have some liberty with changing the primary key: it can be composed of content_id, response_id, and site_id in any order, but cannot contain date.

The application is developed mostly in PHP, so if there is an quicker way to accomplish the same results by splitting the query into subqueries, using temporary tables, or doing things on the application side, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: maybe you can try to index `site_id, date plus content_id` ?

Comment: In InnoDB, the secondary indexes work by pointing to the primary key (and the results are then retrieved by using the primary key). A side effect of this is that all secondary keys essentially have the primary key columns appended at the end. Thus the index (site_id, date) behaves like (site_id, date, content_id, response_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Reposted from comments by request)

Set up a table that has three columns:  id, date, and num_responses.  The column num_responses consists of the number of responses for the given id on the given date.  Backfill the table appropriately, and then at around midnight (or later) each night, run a script that adds a new row for the previous day.

Then, to get the rows you want, you can merely query the table mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calculating each time, how about cache the calculated count since the last query, and add the increment of count to update the cache by putting date condition into the WHERE clause?

Comment: The date range is arbitrary, and the data is frequently updated, so the cache would seldom hit, and if it did, it would most likely be stale. And it still doesn't solve the problem of the initial query being slow/intensive. :/

Comment: date range is arbitrary? does the "date" actually reflect the timestamp of response?

Comment: The date range in the SQL query is arbitrary. That is, the user can select any slice of time to get the statistics for. The date column in the table contains the time the response was made. The aim of this query is to get a list of the most responded to pieces of content during an arbitrary slice of time (a year, a month, 3 days, 2 hours, from any given start and end date). Date is a date/time unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered partitioning the table by date?  Are there any indices on the table?

Comment: William's suggestion is also an excellent idea.  In fact, it would be quite easy to whip up a script to do this that could tally up these totals each night (so, you'd have columns of id, date, and num_responses).  Then, it would be trivial to query this smaller table to get a sum of responses throughout a given date range.  And if it would be too slow to run the script once per day, then you can run it once per hour (or even once every ten minutes), but you'd probably want some kind of auto-incrementing row id so that you can pick up where you left off.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you have the datatype of your date column as an unsigned int instead of a date?

Comment: I'm storing dates as unix timestamps. It's far faster, it keeps the indexes on the date columns smaller, and I handle all the time-zone details on the application side (since I cache data, I store raw times and convert as necessary before presentation).

Comment: With regards to precalculating the data, daily data for 1 year would result in 66,430 rows (365 choose 2) per piece of content with a response, and 266,085 rows for 2 years. Hourly data for 1 year would be 38,365,420 rows. Then multiply that by the number of pieces of content with responses, say 10,000, giving 664,300,000 rows just for the daily data for 1 year. Precalculating just isn't feasible, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Well, you don't have to tally the number of responses for every two-day combination, but rather just tally the number of responses for each individual day.  If you do that, you might have (id,date,num_responses) triples (each of which constitute a row in this rollup table) that might, for example, look like (12345,20101201,2342),(12345,20101202,4349),(23456,20101201,345346),etc.  Let's call this table num_responses_by_id (continued below).

Comment: Then, to get the number of responses per id for a given date range, you can simply do a select id, sum(num_responses) as num_responses from num_responses_by_id where date>=[whatever] and date<=[whatever] group by id

Comment: That would drastically cut down on the number of rows, and would be quick to query. That may be the best option. Even hourly would be only 8760 rows per year, which isn't a brutal amount to calculate on an hourly basis. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. :)